# how does we can access to the member while it's deleted from array?

Tags: javascript

```js
var arr = [{id: 1, name: 'John'}, {id: 2, name: 'Mike'}];

var member = arr[0];

arr.splice(0, 1);

console.log(member);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the problem?

Answer (score 10):

You can keep accessing it because you still have a reference to it. It's no longer in the array, but it still exists. It will continue to exist until all references to it are dropped, and when they are, it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

After this:

```
var arr = [{id: 1, name: 'John'}, {id: 2, name: 'Mike'}];
```

you have something like this in memory (several details omitted):

```
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
arr:Ref4875−−−−−−>|   (array)  |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  | 0: Ref8612 |−−−−−>|   (object)   |
                  | 1: Ref4631 |−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |   | id: 1        |
                                  |   | name: "John" |
                                  |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                  |
                                  |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                  +−−>|   (object)   |
                                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                      | id: 1        |
                                      | name: "John" |
                                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

(The "Ref1234" values are called *object references*. You never see their actual values, but you can think of them as a number the JavaScript engine uses to look up where the object is in memory.)

Then after this:

```
var member = arr[0];
```

both `member` and the array refer to the object, something like this:

```
member:Ref8612−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
arr:Ref4875−−−−−−>|   (array)  |   |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  | 0: Ref8612 |−−−+−>|   (object)   |
                  | 1: Ref4631 |−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |   | id: 1        |
                                  |   | name: "John" |
                                  |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                  |
                                  |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                  +−−>|   (object)   |
                                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                      | id: 1        |
                                      | name: "John" |
                                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then after:

```
arr.splice(0, 1);
```

the array no longer has a reference to it, but `member` still does:

```
                                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
member:Ref8612−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>|   (object)   |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
arr:Ref4875−−−−−−>|   (array)  |      | id: 1        |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+      | name: "John" |
                  | 0: Ref4631 |−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | 
                                  | 
                                  | 
                                  | 
                                  |
                                  |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                  +−−>|   (object)   |
                                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                      | id: 1        |
                                      | name: "John" |
                                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Comment: *You've earned the ASCII art gold badge* :)

Comment: @JonasWilms - Oh, that should *so* be a thing. :-D